# Salvar dados populados do formulário em outra tabela

Tags: php, mysql

O código abaixo recebe dados de uma tabela que posso editar e salvar novamente, porém estava tentando usar esses dados e inserir os mesmos em outra tabela mas não estou conseguindo.

Código que recebe os dados:

```php
<?php
session_start();
include_once("conexao.php");
$id = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$result_usuario = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id = '$id'";
$resultado_usuario = mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuario);
$row_usuario = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_usuario);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Agendamento de manicure</title>     
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="cad_usuario.php">Cadastrar</a><br>
        <a href="index.php">Listar</a><br>
        <h1>Editar UsuĂ¡rio</h1>
        <?php
        if(isset($_SESSION['msg'])){
            echo $_SESSION['msg'];
            unset($_SESSION['msg']);
        }
        ?>
        <form method="POST" action="proc_cad_agendamento.php">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row_usuario['id']; ?>">
            <label>Nome: </label>
            <input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Digite o nome completo" value="<?php echo $row_usuario['nome']; ?>"><br><br>

            <label>CPF: </label>
            <input type="text" name="cpf" placeholder="Digite o seu melhor e-mail" value="<?php echo $row_usuario['cpf']; ?>"><br><br>

            <input type="submit" value="Editar">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Código que processa os dados para inserir em outra tabela:

```php
<?php
session_start();
include_once("conexao.php");
$id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
$nome = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'nome', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$cpf = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'cpf', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

$result_usuario = "INSERT INTO agendamento (id, nome, cpf) VALUES ('$id', '$nome', '$cpf', NOW())";
$resultado_usuario = mysqli_query($conn, $result_usuario);
if(mysqli_insert_id($conn)){
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "<p style='color:green;'>Usuário cadastrado com sucesso</p>";
    header("Location: index.php");
}else{
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "<p style='color:red;'>Usuário não foi cadastrado com sucesso</p>";
    header("Location: cad_usuario.php");
}
```

Comment: por que, re-inserir os dados em outra tabela?

Comment: Aparenta estar correto o código. Já verificou se a tabela tem os tipos de campos e tamanho corretos para receber esses dados?

Comment: Vamos como o "Jack" (por partes)... 1 - Qual erro aparece ou você está tratando os erros? 2 - Qual o nome do arquivo que processa a inserção na nova tabela?

Comment: Vinicius de jesus, porque tenho um sistema de de agendamento de serviço, mando localizar o cliente, ai já me vem um formulário com os dados do cliente que já esta cadastrado em uma tabela, esse formulário tem mais 3 campos funcionário, data e hora quando enviar ele tem que gravar esses dados em uma outra tabela para que eu possa localizar o agendamento por cliente ou por funcionário.

Comment: @MagicHat ai e onde nao estou entendendo,como existe o IF ELSE ele nao mostra erro pois redireciona para mensagem que esta dentro do IF ELSE porem se eu comento o IF ELSE ele fica a pagina em branco sem nenhum erro e nao grava os dados na tabela, ja verifique o verificação de erros esta ativada.

Comment: Qual o nome do arquivo que insere os dados na outra tabela?

Comment: proc_cad_agendamento.php   que seria o segundo código que postei la em cima

Comment: alguém teria mais alguma dica?